# Redirecting to login page when user clicks a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms

I want my anonymous user to be able to navigate throughout the website, but if he presses any button inside the site, he should be redirected to a login page. How do I achieve this?

Are there functions that I should use in the FormAuthentication class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set authentication in files by some setting in in web.config like.

this will allow you to navigate all the pages.
Now for any event in page like button click or something else you can write a function in which you can check authentication and authorization of user by Membership provider
like

```
using System.Security.Authentication

Public void IsValidUser()
{
   if(User.Identity.Name!=string.empty)
     Response.Redirect("~login.aspx");
   else
   {
      if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        Response.Redirect("~login.aspx");
   }
}
```

Comment: Whats the namespace of Identity.Name??

Comment: using System.Security.Authentication;

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to write your own custom code for this (of course, you can use ASP.NET infrastructure). A general outline will be

1. Configure forms authentication so that all pages are marked as unsecured (i.e. anonymous access is allowed)
2. On click on any button, check if user is authenticated or not and if not then redirect to login page (using [FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5szy00dd.aspx) method)

From better use experience, instead of doing post-back in #2, I will generate a java-script that will pop-up the login prompt (a modal dialog) if necessary and do the login via ajax call and then re-submit the form. Using library such as jquery, you can attach the necessary script-let to all submit buttons (or buttons marked with specific class) on the form.

Comment: i wish i knew how to do that pop up.. but i will keep it simiple for now